# Know when RecyclerView items are shown for the first time (Android)

Tags: android, google-analytics, visible, android-recyclerview, staggeredgridlayout

I'm trying to use Google Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce to send "impressions" of my products on a RecyclerView StaggeredGrid. Every time a user scroll, I check which products are visible and send a Hit:

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if (newState == AbsListView.OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        for (int i = firstVisibleItemPosition; i <= lastVisibleItemPosition; i++) {
            Offer offer = mListViewContentFetcher.getApiObjects().get(i);

            Product product = new Product()
                .setId(offer.getCode())
                .setName(offer.getTitle())
                .setCategory(offer.getStore().getName())
                .setPosition(i);

            builder.addImpression(product, "products_list");
        }

        mTracker.setScreenName("Products List");
        mTracker.send(builder.build());
    }
}
```

But I also need to run this when the RecyclerView is built for the first time and the first products are visible.

How can I know that the first items are ready?
I tried using ViewTreeObserver on recyclerview and onBindViewHolder without success.

**Edit:** This is inside a fragment that is used on a viewpager, so I need to know when the items are really visible and not only added.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't you use your RecyclerView.Adapter's [onViewAttachedToWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewAttachedToWindow(VH)) and [onViewDetachedFromWindow](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewDetachedFromWindow(VH)) methods to track when things come in/out of view?

Comment: It seens promissing! The doc is not very helpful describing the method behavior, but I will give it a try. Thanks

Comment: I managed to use onViewAttachedToWindow to accomplish the right result, so I'm setting this as accepted answer. Thank you, @Buddy. What I did was adding impressions on the **onViewAttachedToWindow** if the fragment was visible (using [getUserVisibleHint()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getUserVisibleHint())) and then sending the analytics hit **onPause** of the fragment.

Comment: @petrusgomes  can you share some code of this implementation?

Comment: Sorry, @DivyeshPatel. I don't have access to the code anymore. But if I remember correctly, I kept the impressions in a Map, adding or removing from it as the listeners above got called.